# merging two arrays together in general

Tags: arrays, data-structures, merge

If `A1 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}` and `A2 = {15, 25, 35, 45}` are two arrays, what is the number of comparisons required to merge two arrays will be ?

my Opinion in solvng this problem is

to merge 15, 2 comparisons is enough,
so NOW it will looks like

`A1 = {10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}; A2 = {25, 35, 45}`

to merge 25, 4 comparisons is enough,
so now it will looks like

`A1 = {10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 60}; A2 = {35, 45}`

to merge 35, 6 comparisons is enough,
so now it will looks like

`A1 = {10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 50, 60}; A2 = {45}`

to merge 45, 8 comparisons is enough,
so now it will looks like

`A1 = {10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60}`

hence, 20 comparisons is enough.
But it's not.

what do you say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like two lines of people, and you are the bank teller.  So long as there are two people at the front of the respective lines, you must compare them to decide which to take.  After one line is empty, you can attach all the remaining people from the other line with no comparisons.  (This analogy is assuming the inputs are linked lists.  If you're merging arrays, then the tail of the other line must be copied and the answer is different.)

With all this in mind, it's not hard to see that the number of comparisons depends on the values you're merging.  At a minimum it's min(m, n) where m and n are the lengths of the inputs.  At maximum it's m + n - 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't compare (everytime) the elements in the array(s) from 0. While merging two arrays, you use an extra array where you keep your elements as they are sorted and merged.

In your case, you keep a third array - `B` where `B.length = A1.length+A2.length`.

The merging of the arrays and corresponding number comparisons look like following:-

```
A1[0]<A2[0] --> B[0] = A1[0]
A1[1]>A2[0] --> B[1] = A2[0]  // total number of comparisons is 2

A1[1]<A2[1] --> B[2] = A1[1]
A1[2]>A2[1] --> B[3] = A2[1] // total number of comparisons is 4

A1[2]<A2[2] --> B[4] = A1[2]
A1[3]>A2[2] --> B[5] = A2[2] //total number of comparisons is 6

A1[3]<A2[3] --> B[6] = A1[3]
A1[4]>A2[3] --> B[7] = A2[3] //total number of comparisons is 8
```

After this, there are no elements left in B. Hence, we copy the remaining elements in B.

The resulting array is as follows:-

B = {10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,60}

So, the total number of comparisons is 8 and not 20.

Comment: Don't forget that many times you are merging linked lists destructively (changing the inputs to make the output).

Comment: @Gene I do know that. I was just explaining the question while keeping the focus on arrays because that's what OP wanted.